# Troubles creating a new cakephp plugin in a working application + wrong usage of requestAction

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to create a new plugin for my (already working) cakephp application. I have followed the manual with the exact same data (ContactManager plugin, Contacts controller etc.), but when I try to load it by using its url (example.com/contact_manager/contacts/index), cakephp complains that LanguageController (which is called with a requestAction from my layout file) is not in my plugin path. It shouldn't be there indeed, since it is an application controller...

What am I doing wrong?

I'm not posting code because I used exactly the same code as the cakephp manual, here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

Comment: the code generating the error isn't on the page you've linked to. While I've already answered the question please add `is called with a requestAction from my layout file` to the question so that it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The current plugin and prefix persist

If you do the following:

```
$this->requestAction(array(
    'controller' => 'x', 
    'action' => 'y'
));
```

And the current request is in your app, you're requesting the equivalent of the url:

```
/x/y
```

If you are in your foo plugin, the same code is the equivalent of the url:

```
/foo/x/y
```

To always request something from your app, define with a falsey value the key 'plugin':

```
$this->requestAction(array(
    'controller' => 'x', 
    'action' => 'y', 
    'plugin' => false
));
```

OR use a string url.

### You're doing something odd

> CakePHP complains that LanguageController (which is called with a requestAction from my layout file)

It's *not normal* to use requestAction like that - you should *send* information to the view (meaning the view layer - the view class, view files, layouts, elements, helpers). You don't *ask* for information in the view. Writing code like that is a recipe for problems. For example if the language controller throws an exception - all urls will be an error.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has been terribly userful :)

Comment: About the wrong usage of requestAction, I know that wiews should only display information and that they should not ask for them, but I can't see a better way to retrieve those informations only when I need them. For example, I'm using the theme class, and I have to show languages only in some themes... I could pass that data from a controller, but it would be useless most of the time... is there a better way to do that?